# Do not propagate headers on HTTP redirects

Tags: django, http, redirect, amazon-s3, http-headers

I have files hosted on Amazon S3, and I'd like to download them after a treatment in my app. This app view requires the HTTP Authorization header to proceed. Here is the process:

1. Query view `/file/xxx` with the required `Authorization` request header
2. If the app access is granted, does some treatment
3. Generate a signed S3 url, and redirect to it

The fact is that the request header is also propagated on the redirect, and is in conflict with Amazon's S3 signature, I have the following error message:

> Either the Signature query string parameter or the Authorization header should be specified, not both

So, is there a way to not propagate the `Authorization` header to S3 ?

Note that I have tested all `3xx` HTTP codes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: It is the responsibility of the client to propagate or not the header and seems variable... From memory, I bypassed the conflict passing my authorization token through a GET parameter.

Comment: Thank you, in my case, the devil is in the details, unfortunately: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33714122

Answer (score 2):

It may depend on your client, for example see: https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=4800

It appears curl won't carry over your Authorization header by default. But I'm dealing with a similar issue and I see that by default http components appears to carry it.

Answer (score 0):

Is your S3 file path on the same domain as your `/file/xxx`? That would explain why the Authorization header is being sent, presumably. If you have your S3 hosted on a different domain to the app view, then I would assume the Authorization header would not be sent to the S3 domain (as HTTP Authorization is per-domain).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Matthew, but this is precisely not on the same domain. `/file/xxx` is local, backed by Django on my development computer.