# Omit specific headers after being redirected

Tags: http, redirect

I have a web server which contains an API to upload files to Amazon's S3 storage. Since I do not want to waste resources on streaming the files through my server, when an upload request comes in, I generate a [pre-signed URL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property) for the client and then redirect that client to this URL using [HTTP 307 - Temporary redirect](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.7).

In practice, the flow looks like this:

1. Client issues a *PUT* request to my server, requesting a file upload
2. My server inspects the request and generates a pre-signed URL for S3
3. My server responds to client with 307 redirection to the pre-signed URL
4. Client repeats the *PUT* request to the pre-signed URL
5. Upload commences

### The challenge

My server uses the *[Authorization](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.8)* header for... well, authorisation. Incidentally, Amazon also accepts this header for authorisation, although the values expected by both parties are completely different.

The problem is, that since my upload API requires this header to be present during file upload request, when my server issues the 307 redirect back to the client, the client takes all the headers in the original request and sends them along to the pre-signed S3 URL, **which causes the request to be rejected by Amazon due to authorisation error**.

### The question

Can I somehow instruct the client (via HTTP response header) to **not** include the *Authorization* header when following the redirection?

### Current solution

Right now we "fixed" this by returning the pre-signed URL to the client in the response body. The client then manually issues a new *PUT* request to that URL without the *Authorization* header. This works fine. I would like to know if there is a way to achieve this behaviour without this extra manual work.

> **What is the client?** In the above statements, when I mention the "client", right now it could be either a modern web browser or a native iOS or Android app. On iOS, we use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) for HTTP communication. I am unsure of what library or components are used on Android.
>
> **Note:** I have seen [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159748/do-not-propagate-headers-on-http-redirects), but it does not contain the answers I seek.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I do not think it is possible as per the HTTP standard. The only working solution was the one described in _Current solution_.